# Jquery Validation live validation of form by form element id and submit form by ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form.I want to live validate this form with jquery validation plug-in.After finishing Validataion of the form i want to submit it by ajax.I want to validate every fields of the form by its id.
  I have done this so far:

```
 <form id="booking-form" name="booking-form" method="post" class="form-horizontal"> 
      <input type="text" id="firstname" value="" name="book[firstname]">
   <input type="text" id="email" value="" name="book[email]">
   <input type="text" id="contact" value="" name="book[contact]">
      <input type="submit" id="submit-booking"  class="btn btn-primary btn-large" value="Book Now"/>
```

In my javascript function:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#booking-form").validate({
    rules: {
        "book[firstname]": {
            required: true
        },
        "book[email]": {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        "book[contact]": {
            required: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {

    alert("fff");
        var formData = $(form).serialize();
        //alert(formData);


        $.ajax({
            url: "bs_client_function.php?action=new_b",
            type: "post",
            data: formData,
            beforeSend: function () {

            },
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
        return false;

    }
});
        });
```

It did not work.No validation error shows in the form and no ajax request is sending.How i overcome this problems??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some serious problems...

1)  There is absolutely no need to put `.validate()` inside of a click handler.  It's supposed to go inside the DOM ready event handler.  Why?  Because `.validate()` is how you *initialize* the plugin, not a method to test the form.  Testing is done automatically once the plugin is initialized on your form.

2)  When the rules are declared inside `.validate()`, they can only be assigned by field `name`, **not** by `id` and not by jQuery selector.

3)  You should really use a button inside of the form rather than a link.  The submit button is captured automatically by the plugin.

4)  You spelled `required` incorrectly on your third field.

```
"#contact": {requred: true}
```

---

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/P5tVp/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#booking-form").validate({
        rules: {
            "b[firstname]": {
                required: true
            },
            "b[email]": {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            "book[contact]": {
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var formData = $(form).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "bs_client_function.php?action=new_b",
                type: "post",
                data: formData,
                beforeSend: function () {

                },
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi Sparky Thanks for your awesome answer.It works in Fiddle.But I don not why its not working in my code.I have updated my code above.Please take a look.It direct submits my form no ajax request sending here.And no error validation works.

Comment: Hi Sparky, Its work :) . I have a problem with jquery plugin version.I have updated and its work fine now.